# Why react strictmode initializes localstorage

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-strictmode

**Before removing strictmode**

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

console.log(localStorage.getItem("comments")

```
[{"name":"1","comment":"asdjflisadhj"}]
[]
```

**removing strictmode**

index.js

```
...
root.render(<App />);
...
```

console.log(localStorage.getItem("comments")

```
[{"name":"1","comment":"asdjflisadhj"}]
```

Local storage finally did it normally.
But I wonder why strict mode initialized local storage.

```
const Info = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [comment, setComment] = useState("");
  const [comments, setComments] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
    const savedComments = localStorage.getItem("comments");
    if (savedComments) {
      setComments(JSON.parse(savedComments));
    }
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("comments"));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("comments", JSON.stringify(comments));
  }, [comments]);

...
```

Comment: Please post the part of your app code that interacts with the localstorage, as well as where exactly you are doing the logging

Comment: It's the `localStorage.setItem("comments", …)` effect that sets the localstorage to the initial value of `comments`, which is an empty array. The `getItem` effect that is running twice just exposes this. Congratulations, strict mode has found a bug in your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about how StrictMode uses localstorage. What is special is *intentionally* calling several functions, that are expected to be pure, twice - which that might be the real root cause in your case. [Quoting the docs](https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure):

> React assumes that every component you write is a pure function. This
> means that React components you write must always return the same JSX
> given the same inputs (props, state, and context).
>
> Components breaking this rule behave unpredictably and cause bugs. To
> help you find accidentally impure code, Strict Mode calls some of your
> functions (only the ones that should be pure) **twice in development**.
> This includes:
>
> - Your component function body (only top-level logic, so this doesn’t
>   include code inside event handlers)
> - Functions that you pass to
>   useState, set functions, useMemo, or useReducer
> - Some class component
>   methods like constructor, render, shouldComponentUpdate
>
> [...]
>
> When Strict Mode is on, React will also **run one extra setup+cleanup** cycle in development for every Effect. This may feel surprising, but it helps reveal subtle bugs that are hard to catch manually.